# office 365 calendar api C#

Tags: office365api

I am building an outlook calendar in Winforms using API and C#. But I am not able to create application in Microsoft website.

getting below error while creating application in WPF

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoYrd.png)

I need to get Application ID to go ahead with Office 365 calendar.

Please help me out with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

It mentions:

> New app registrations should be created and managed in the new
>   Application Registration Portal to be compatible with Outlook.com.
>
> Only create new app registrations in the Azure Management Portal if
>   your app:
>
> - Uses the OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant Flow, or Needs to access other Office 365 workloads besides Outlook (such as OneDrive for
>     Business or SharePoint)
> - Bear in mind that apps registered using the Azure Management Portal will not be compatible with Outlook.com, and will not be able to
>     dynamically request permissions scopes. Existing app registrations
>     that were created in the the Azure Management Portal will continue to
>     work for Office 365 only. These registrations do not show up in the
>     Application Registration Portal and must be managed in the Azure
>     Management Portal.
>
> **Account requirements**
>
> In order to use the Application Registration Portal, you need either an Office 365 work or school account, or a
>   Microsoft account. If you don't have either of these, you have a
>   number of options:
>
> - Sign up for a new Microsoft account here.
> - You can obtain an Office 365 subscription in a couple of different ways:
>
>   - You can get a free one-year Office 365 Developer subscription by signing up for the Office Developer program.
>   - You can signup for a 25-user free trial of the Office 365 Business subscription.
>
> **REST API availability**
>
> The REST API is currently enabled on all Office 365 accounts that have Exchange Online, and all Outlook.com
>   accounts.